# Why is Geometry nodes spawning two instances on a point?

Tags: geometry-nodes

For some reason when a specific tree spawns another spawns with it and I cannot figure out why.

[image]

My node tree is super simple.

[image]

I tried looking at the geometry to see if something got duplicated. Clearing parents, reimporting the trees. REnaming the trees. Increasing the Distance Min. Changing the random values. Tried a different base mesh. Always these two trees coming together. What... is going on?

Comment: please upload simplified blend file so we can check it out

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I would say, just slightly increase the value on the distribute points on faces `Distance Min` value, something like 0.01 or whatever proportional to your scale. Try testing it on different values, though it might make the trees slightly distant...

Comment: This was already tried/mentioned in the post. It's always the same tree so I don't think it's a spawning issue.

Comment: Oh I guess then it must be something else.